# How can I eliminate garbage value in this output?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

In this below program, I'm trying to marge 2 arrays into a single vector, but while returning the function I'm getting additional garbage values along with it.

Please anyone suggest me how to remove those!

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

vector <int> merge(int a[],int b[]){
  vector <int> marr1;
  marr1.clear();
  int i=0,j=0;
  while(i+j <= ((*(&a+1)-a)+(*(&b+1)-b)))
  {
    if ((i<= *(&a+1)-a)){
      marr1.push_back(a[i]);
      i++;
    }
    else{
       marr1.push_back(b[j]);
      j++;
    }
  }
  sort(marr1.begin(),marr1.end());
return marr1;
}

int main(){
  //array imlementation
  int arr1[] = {5,7,4,5},arr2[] = {8,3,7,1,9};
  vector <int> ans;
  ans.clear();
  ans = merge(arr1,arr2);
  for (auto i=ans.begin();i<ans.end();++i){
    cout<<*i<<"\t";
  }
}
```

output produced:

```
0   0   0   0   1   3   4   5   5   7   7   8   9   32614   32766   4207952 1400400592
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: It would be helpful to include both the output you are getting and the expected output.

Comment: How do you know how many elements is in a[] and b[]?  `i+j <= ((*(&a+1)-a)+(*(&b+1)-b)))` doesn't look right to me.  In plain c, you have to pass a size as arrays degrade to pointers, or pass the values in via a vector which maintains size.

Comment: Sure ! $ clang++-7 -pthread -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp
$ ./main
$0   0   0   0   1   3   4   5   5   7   7   8   9   32614   32766   4207952 1400400592

Comment: @TarunvigneshSelvabalaji please but any clarifications _into the question_. You can [edit] the question.

Comment: @TarunvigneshSelvabalaji Can you add(edit your question to include) the expected input and output of your program.

Comment: If you don't know, stl has a merge() function already in <algorithm>.

Comment: Will include the length of array

Comment: Please run it under `valgrind` and fix all errors reported there. (It will give you the exact line numbers with a `-g`-compiled binary.) Until then it is just guesswork. BTW, your attempts at guessing the array sizes are completely wrong.

Comment: Try doing `std::cout<<"(*(&a+1)-a): "<<(*(&a+1)-a)<<std::endl;
   std::cout<<"(*(&b+1)-b)): "<<(*(&b+1)-b))<<std::endl;` and see what it prints. It's garbage. The expressions are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>    // <<<< dont use #include <bits/stdc++.h>,
                        //      but include the standard headers

using namespace std;

vector <int> mergeandsort(int a[], int lengtha, int b[], int lengthb) {  // <<<< pass the lengths of the arrays
  vector <int> marr1;                                                    // <<<< and use meaningful names
  // marr1.clear(); <<<< not needed

  for (int i = 0; i < lengtha; i++)
  {
    marr1.push_back(a[i]);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < lengthb; i++)
  {
    marr1.push_back(b[i]);
  }

  sort(marr1.begin(), marr1.end());
  return marr1;
}

int main() {
  int arr1[] = { 5,7,4,5 }, arr2[] = { 8,3,7,1,9 };
  vector <int> ans;
  // ans.clear();   <<<< not needed
  ans = mergeandsort(arr1, 4, arr2, 5);
  for (auto i = ans.begin(); i < ans.end(); ++i) {
    cout << *i << "\t";
  }
}
```

Look at the `<<<<` comments for explanations.

There is still room for improvement:

- passing the hard coded lengths of the arrays in `mergeandsort(arr1, 4, arr2, 5)` is bad practice, if you add/remove element from the arrays, you need to change the lengths too.
- you shouldn't use raw arrays in the first place but vectors like in `vector<int> arr1[] = { 5,7,4,5 };`, then you don't need to care about the sizes as a vectors knows it's own size. I leave this as an exercise for you.

Comment: [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) (C++20) can replace the pair pointer+size.

Answer (score 1):

You pass two `int[]` which degrade to pointers.  This means you cannot tell the number of elements which you attempt to do with `i+j <= ((*(&a+1)-a)+(*(&b+1)-b))`.  Either pass in a length of each array, or even better (C++) pass in two vectors instead.  Also, if you don't know the STL has a `merge()` function in `<algorithm>`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not passing the length of the array, there is no way inside the `merge` function to know about their length. Your program seems to produce **undefined behavior** as can be seen [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/urNUGpPe1uvNsWNT). If you execute this program again and again you'll notice that the output changes which is an indication of undefined behavior.

Secondly, you're using `std::vector::clear` when there is no need to use it in your program. I have commented it in the code example i have given below.

You can use pass the length of the arrays as arguments to the merge function. [Below](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tuqW3YVx4luKDTZ9) is the complete working example:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

vector<int> merge(int a[], int lengthA, int b[], int lengthB){
  vector <int> marr1;
  //marr1.clear();//no need for this since the vector is empty at this point
  for(int i = 0; i< lengthA; ++i)
  {
      //std::cout<<"adding: "<<a[i]<<std::endl;
      marr1.push_back(a[i]);
  }
  for(int i = 0; i< lengthB; ++i)
  {
      //std::cout<<"adding: "<<b[i]<<std::endl;
      marr1.push_back(b[i]);
  }
  sort(marr1.begin(),marr1.end());
return marr1;
}

int main(){
  //array imlementation
  int arr1[] = {5,7,4,5},arr2[] = {8,3,7,1,9};
  vector <int> ans;
  //ans.clear();//no need for this since the vector is empty at this point
  ans = merge(arr1,4, arr2, 5);
  for (auto i=ans.begin();i<ans.end();++i){
    cout<<*i<<"\t";
  }
}
```